# How to know if the locale currently used by the app differs from system locale

Tags: android, locale, android-resources

I want to create a function that returns `true` if the App is in "default locale mode" due to missing locale resources for the current OS locale settings.

`getResources().getConfiguration().locale` returns me the current locale for the OS setting

but I haven't found an equivalent function to see the locale the App is currently using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which locale the app is using, call:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()//for the value of the language, e.g. 'English'
```

Also take  a look at the corresponding Android Developers article:
[Locale | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale)